# Filling a MS Word table with data from MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I try to fill data from my access table into a word table.

In the beginning I have an empty table with 1 row and 2 columns in the word template, when it runs through the code I have finally a table with 8 rows and 2 columns, which is good. One more then I have datasets in access tables, but ok...

But all fields in the tables are empty, why is it not filling the cells with:

```
.Tables(2).Cell(row, col).Range.Text = rs!short
```

Here is the loop:

```
Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tbl_abbreviations", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.MoveFirst
    col = 1
    row = 1
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    .Tables(2).Cell(row, col).Range.Text = rs!short
    col = col + 1
    .Tables(2).Cell(row, col).Range.Text = rs!Description
    .Tables(2).Rows.Add
    col = 1
    row = row + 1

    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

and even a bit strange is that this will work:

```
.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBlue
```

but this doesn't work:

```
.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = RGB(104, 212, 248)
```

did I forgot to activate something?

Comment: Sort of a wild guess, but `Short` is a reserved word, so try `rs![short]`. Other than that, if you are sure that `.Tables(2)` is the correct one, your code should work.

Comment: yeah i am sure with the table. i can change the background color, the number of rows. it is only not showing the text even if i try to write a simple string like "hello". i tryed it even with selection, but did not work.  my think is that i forget to import one library. but word 16.0 library is active

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your approach is not optimal. Writing to a Word table, cell-by-cell, is inefficient.

Much better would be to write your data to a delimited string format, assign that string to a "target" Range location in the Word document (usually a bookmark) then convert the Range to a table, which you can then format.

Sample data content in delimited string format:

```
Short;Description
s1;the first record
s2;the second record
s3;and so on...
```

Code snippet for writing to a bookmark and converting to a table:

```
Dim sData As String
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim tbl As word.Table

sData = "Short;Description" & vbCr & "s1;the first record" & vbCr _
        & "s2;the second record" & vbCr & "s3;and so on..."
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("test").Range
rng.Text = sData
Set tbl = rng.ConvertToTable(";")
```

Substitute your code for reading the Access table and writing it to sData. You can use any field delimiter you want, it doesn't have to be a semicolon. But the record delimiter must be vbCr (ANSI 13). Be sure to specify the field delimiter you use in the ConvertToTable function.

Once you have the `tbl` object you can use it to apply formattting. That's more reliable and efficient than trying to work with a table repeatedly using the `Tables(index)` collection approach.